# start activity from broadcast receiver in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

in my application i'm starting activity from broadcastreceiver.
but after running code it shows activity first.i want it after if condition is true-

-

```
 wwhile ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
         System.out.println("Reading line...");
         flag=false;
         if(line.contains("cmp=com.android.gallery")){
            flag=true;
            break;      
         }
      }

      if(flag==true){

          Intent ii = new Intent(context,PasswordWindow.class);
            ii.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(ii);
      }
```

manifest file-

```
 <activity android:name="com.example.app.PasswordWindow"></activity>
    <receiver android:name="com.example.app.Broadcast">
        <intent-filter >

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: any crash ? or only showig blank screen?

Comment: check your layout file .. check if you set your layout in activity

Comment: correct layout is there..

Comment: debug and check if the startActivity is called or not

Comment: you sure about this line?? line.contains("cmp=com.android.gallery")

Comment: yes.that line is working..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28557/discussion-between-stinepike-and-yuva)